# What namespace to use for code that "augments std"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, idioms

Sometimes you find yourself writing some bits of header code which could really have fit nicely into the C++ standard library. Just as an example: a `disable_if` template, doing the converse of [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

I don't want to just put it in the global namespace. But what's the convention? Should I...

- add it to `namespace std`?
- add it to `namespace std::experimental`?
- add it to something like `namespace std::augmented`?
- add it to something like `namespace myprojectname::std`?
- add it to something like `namespace std-augmented`?
- something else?

Comment: I've seen someone (don't remember whether was Stroustrup or Hinnant) using `estd` or `Estd`, in the sense of *extended std*; it's a *private* convention though, I guess.

Comment: Putting it in `namespace std` is UB.

Comment: It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std.

Comment: I have a VS project `SDK` which is included to all solutions I write. It contains all such code in `SDK` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

As it is undefined to put it in namespace `std`

I would use:

```
namespace extended_std /* or more appropriate name */
{
    namespace std
    {
        // disable_if
    }
}
```

And potentially

```
using namespace extended_std; // So you can use std::disable_if
```

Comment: Aside from the using directive having the wrong syntax, wouldn't that just cause ambiguity errors?

Comment: @SebastianRedl: (syntax fixed). It would be indeed be ambiguous if you use same name as in original std, but the goal is to extend and not replace `std`.

Answer (score 2):

All identifiers are reserved inside the `std` namespace. You'll have to define your own. The name of this namespace is opinon-based, but if I were you I'd define a `utils::` or `stdext::` namespace somewhere. As I never stumbled upon such a case, I can't say what's the usual choice.

---

As a reminder, here are the list of reserved identifiers in C++:

- Reserved in any scope, including for use as implementation macros:

  - identifiers beginning with an underscore followed immediately by an uppercase letter
  - identifiers containing adjacent underscores (or "double underscore")
- Reserved in the global namespace:

  - identifiers beginning with an underscore
- Everything in the std namespace is reserved (you are allowed to add template specializations, though).

---

From the 2003 C++ Standard:

> #### 17.4.3.2.1 Global names [lib.global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.<sup>165</sup>
>
> <sup>165)</sup> Such names are also reserved in namespace ::std (17.4.3.1).
>
> #### 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and
>   optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
>     underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
>     with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
> - Each macro name in any of the following subclauses (including the future library
>     directions) is reserved for use as specified if any of its associated headers is included;
>     unless explicitly stated otherwise (see 7.1.4).
> - All identifiers with external linkage in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) are always reserved for use as identifiers with external
>     linkage.<sup>154</sup>
> - Each identifier with file scope listed in any of the following subclauses (including the
>     future library directions) is reserved for use as a macro name and as an identifier with
>     file scope in the same name space if any of its associated headers is included.
>
> No other identifiers are reserved. If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.
>
> If the program removes (with `#undef`) any macro definition of an identifier in the first
>   group listed above, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>154)</sup> The list of reserved identifiers with external linkage includes `errno`, `math_errhandling`, `setjmp`, and `va_end`.

Comment: Ok, so not `std`, but what do people usually do instead?